# Unity/Ubuntu Desktops loading up on KDE?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

[image]
Sometimes when I log into Kubuntu 14.10, my first desktop is fine, but then when I switch to others, all my widgets are gone and it has the Ubuntu default background, and when I go back to my first desktop I saw when I logged in, it has lost all its widgets as well and has the Ubuntu default background too. I fix this be logging in and back out, but it's still a bit annoying.

Also, when I switch to one of these desktops, I can no longer use the mouse wheel to change virtual desktops. Just saying in case that might give a little more info as to what the issue is.

Here is my output for `lspci -v`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2010
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
    Memory at f7a14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f7a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at f7a1e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7a1c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
    Memory at f7a10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7900000-f79fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7800000-f78fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000f2100000-00000000f21fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7a1b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7a1a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at f7a19000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 745] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1065
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 52
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1065
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0208
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Expansion ROM at f7980000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    I/O ports at d000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f2100000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Why do people just skip right over my question? It had 6 views while most of the questions that came a while after it got way more views.

Comment: It probab'y means they don't know what the solution is (I don't either) - I have had a similar issue with switching user with the default desktop on 14.04 and the mouse cursor not appearing. What hardware and graphics are you using (you can use `lspci -v`)

Comment: Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 05d7
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
        Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915

Comment: Is this normal? I have a GeForce GTX 745, is this the showing details of the onboard graphics? I have my HDMI cable plugged into my graphics card..

Comment: It should have a separate entry for your other graphics card (it shows both integrated and discrete graphics). You can add the output to your question using the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/587810/edit) button.